# Проблема с отображением картинок в Django

Tags: python, django

Я новичок в Django. Не могу реализовать отображение картинок на странице.что не так?

**SETTINGS.PY**

```
STATIC_URL = '/static/'

STATICFILES_DIRS = (
    os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", ),
)

MEDIA_URL = '/media/'
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, "static", "media")
```

**MODELS.PY**

```
class ProductImage(models.Model):
    product = models.ForeignKey(Product, blank=True, null=True, default=None, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    image = models.ImageField(upload_to='products_images/')
    is_main = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    is_active = models.BooleanField(default=True)
    created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True, auto_now=False)
    updated = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=False, auto_now=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return "%s" % self.id

    class Meta:
        verbose_name = 'Photo'
        verbose_name_plural = 'Photos'
```

**URLS.PY**

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from landing import views

urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^', views.home, name='home'),
    url(r'^landing/', views.landing, name='landing')
]
```

**VIEWS.PY**

```
from django.http import HttpResponseRedirect
from django.shortcuts import render
from products.models import *
from .forms import SabscribersForm


def landing(request):
    name = "CoderMax"
    # current_day = "22.02.2020"
    # current_day = datetime.datetime.today()
    # print(current_day.strftime("%m/%d/%Y"))
    form = SabscribersForm(request.POST or None)

    if request.method == "POST" and form.is_valid():
        print(request.POST)
        print(form.cleaned_data)

        new_form = form.save()
        return HttpResponseRedirect(request.META.get('HTTP_REFERER'))

    return render(request, 'landing/landing.html', locals())


def home(request):
    products_images = ProductImage.objects.filter(is_active=True, is_main=True)
    return render(request, 'landing/home.html', locals())
```

**HOME.HTML**

```
 {% for product_image in products_images %}
                    <div class="col-lg-3">
                        <div class="product-item">
                            <div>
                                <img src="{{ product_image.image.url }}" class="img-responsive" alt="img">
                            </div>
                            <h6>{{ product_image.product.name }}</h6>
                            <p>
                                {{ product_image.product.description|truncatechars_html:50 }}
                            </p>
                            <div>
                                {{ product_image.product.price }} UAH
                            </div>
                            <div class="add-to-card-btn">
                                <button class="btn btn-success">
                                    Add to Card
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>
                </div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

в urls.py файле проекта есть?

```
+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root=settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

Comment: Добавил, но так же нет изменение и без падения )

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko точно в файл проекта? там где путь в admin указан?

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko в settings.py в `MIDDLEWARE`  `django.template.context_processors.media` есть?

Comment: django.template.context_processors.media добавил и страница упала, а вот по " точно в файл проекта? там где путь в admin указан?" не понял вопрос (

Comment: После добавления MIDDLEWARE django.template.context_processors.media  вот что пишет в сейтингс.пу  Unresolved reference 'media' 
 Inspection info: This inspection detects names that should resolve but don't. Due to dynamic dispatch and duck typing, this is possible in a limited but useful number of cases. Top-level and class-level items are supported better than instance items.

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko извеняюсь, это не в middleware a в `TEMPLATES` там где  `OPTIONS` `'context_processors'`

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko файл urls.py которой в той же директории где и settings.py

Comment: Все поправил ) падение прекратилось ) но картинок нет ((( сделал как вы сказали (

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko может стоит задать контекст явно а не через local(). `return render(request, 'landing/home.html',{'products_images':products_images})`

Comment: я прошу прощения, а где это прописать ? я просто чайник чайником )))

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko в  `def home(request):`

Comment: а в каком файле все это делать ?)

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko ну у вас же функции в views.py описаны

Comment: не сработало ((( уже не знаю как и быть (((

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko а изображение то вообще есть?)

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko если есть возможность закиньте свой проет на гидхаб и скиньте ссылку

Comment: картинки есть ) в консольке на них отображатся путь но ничего не работат. вот ссылка https://github.com/MaksimSerbichenko/djangoProjectTest.git

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko вы сами все это писали? почему у вас модель в одной папке с приложением а в другом приложение во views.py описана логика выгрузки из это модели? почему папка media находится где-то в папке статик?

Comment: пишу сам, с медиа, я поправил так как не запушил после ваших подсказок. вс остальное подсматривал на ютюбе

Comment: я так понимаю что у меня все запущено, да ?

Comment: @MaksymSerbichenko ну как по мне то да (то что у вас в проекте 3 приложения, есть три файла моделей, но вы описываете логику в одном приложении в 1 файле views. все роуты в одном urls, я сам не гуру django и учу не столь давно но такую структуру вряд ли можно назвать правильной  ) https://github.com/vadimsharoikin/prezent
простой пример загрузки изображений и их выгрузка в слайдер. Посмотрите, думаю там все поймете и вам будет проще поправить в своем

Comment: огромное вам спасибо )

Answer (score 0):

Почему у вас в настройке MEDIA_ROOT присутствует static? Папка с media должна расположение отдельно, вне папки static, исправьте на:

```
MEDIA_ROOT = os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'media')
```

Comment: Поправил в медиа рут, так же вынес папку медиа отдельно от статик, но ничего не изменилось, но и не упало )